# Конвертирование двухбайтовых символов в php

Tags: кодировка, php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно перевести двухбайтовый символ из одной кодировки в другую т.е. из utf-8 в cp1251 на php. Т.е. скажем я хочу преобразовать букву "г" из utf-8 в cp1251.
Насколько я понимаю, я получаю два символа [syntax=php]Р[/syntax] и [syntax=php]і[/syntax], т.е. два байта, а как мне теперь как мне их сложить, или перевести в десятичное представление, чтобы потом произвести какое-либо действие, например вычесть 848, чтобы получить тотже номер в системе cp1251

Интересует именно способ, а не готовые функции

Comment: Может iconv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@platedz](/users/11283/platedz)](/users/11283/platedz), безотносительно ПХП.

Символы utf-8 надо переводить в коды ucs, а их (если это возможно) в cp1251. Естественно не все ucs (например: latin-1, псевдографика, иероглифы и т.д.)  могут быть переведены в cp1251.

*Как переводить utf-8 в ucs.*

Смотрим первый (знаковый) бит байта utf-8. Если это 0, то код ucs равен значению этого байта (это ascii).

Если первые два бита это 10 или значение байта 0xff или 0xfe, то это ошибка в utf-8.

Теперь проанализируем *старшие* биты байта. Выделим  несколько  1, а потом один 0. Количество единичек равно количеству байт utf-8, кодирующих ucs. Оставшаяся часть байта это старшие биты кодируемого ucs. При этом все следующие байты данного символа должны начинаться с **10** и остающиеся в них 6 бит кодируют очередную часть ucs.

Вся кириллица кодируется 2 байтами utf-8. Например, русская **А** (ucs код 0x410) в utf-8 это 2 байта 0xd0 0x90

```
1101 0000  1001 0000  запишем так 
  (слева видим 110, значит всего будет 2 байта в utf-8)
110 10000  10 010000  выделим 11 бит 
  (5 из первого и 6 из второго байт) из которых формируем ucs
10000010000 или разбив на полубайты  
100 0001 0000 т.е. 0x410
```

Другой пример это символ **№**

```
№ в utf-8   0xe2 0x84 0x96
1110 0010   1000 0100  1001 0110
     0010     00 0100    01 0110
     0010 0001 0001 0110 == 0x2116
```

Вообще-то быстрее написать программу (мне проще на Си, но Вас интересует ПХП), чем объяснять русскими словами.

Для 2-х байт в str[], получив в b1 первые 5 бит, а в b2 последние 6

```
int b1, b2, ucs;
b1 = str[0] & 0x1f; b2 = str[1] & 0x3f;
ucs = (b1 << 6) | b2;
```

или если в ПХП нет битовых операций (надеюсь остаток от деления есть), то

```
b1 = str[0] % 32; b2 = str[1] % 64;
ucs = b1*64 + b2;
```

Answer (score 2):

Поверьте, для этого проще использовать "готовую функцию" - [mb_convert_encoding](http://docs.php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) или [iconv](http://docs.php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv.php). Ну а если все же хочется пострадать, то изучайте информацию: [раз](http://www.unicode.org/), [два](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), [три](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), [четыре](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Юникод).

Answer (score 1):

Конечно вопрос старый но, многие люди щяс побегут писать не пойми что. Есть стандарт функции по переводу строк в массив байтов php и наоборот.

```
unpack('C*', $buffer) в нем вы получите массив int со значениями обычных байтов(в пхп нету байтовских массивов)
pack('C*', $ta) обратная функция.
```